# Issue using Ember.set on Component property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Component which receives a `model` attribute in some template:

```
{{#client-user-pipeline-step model=step tasks=step.tasks routeOnOpenAddTaskModal=(route-action "onOpenAddTaskModal")
    routeOnOpenEditTextModal=(route-action "onOpenEditTextModal")}}
{{/client-user-pipeline-step}}
```

As per my understanding, this will be stored as an `Ember.Object` instance complete with property observers and stuff inside the component. Now when I try to change some property of the `model` by simply assigning a value to it I get this error:

```
You must use Ember.set() to set the `name` property (of [object Object])
```

Which is exactly what I expect as the property is being observed due to data binding. Now when I try to change the value using `Ember.set` like in `this.getModel().set('name', name) ;` I get this error:

```
this.getModel(...).set is not a function
```

Wow great! I couldn't find a precise explanation of how this data binding thing is supposed to work in the docs, so I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me on the whole idea and this issue in particular. Thanks!

UPDATE:

The `getModel()` function is a shorthand for `this.get('model')`.

Comment: what is `getModel` function ? if it is returning `Ember.Object` then you can use `this.set` otherwise you need to use `Ember.set`.

Comment: I updated the answer. Using Ember.set works but DOM doesn't get updated.

Comment: `model=step` - here what is the `step` ? please include relevant code for step. Is it `Ember.Object` ?. and include `client-user-pipeline-step` hbs relevant code too

Comment: @kumkanillam I already solved it using `Ember.set`. Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: @Parsoa If `this.set` is not working but `Ember.set` I would bet your underlying object is not an `Ember.Object`.